# How does one solve the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve the following differential equation? This is a reduced mass balance equation for a cylinder containing a gas mixture of two gases (here represented by the numbers 1 and 2)):

$$\frac{P_{1}C_{V_{1}}^{*}}{RT_{1}}\frac{dT_{1}}{dt} + \frac{P_{2}C_{V_{2}}^{*}}{RT_{2}}\frac{dT_{2}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left ( \frac{P_{1}}{T_{1}} \right ) T_{1} + \frac{d}{dt}\left ( \frac{P_{2}}{T_{2}} \right ) T_{2}$$

The only constants are $C_{V_{1}}, C_{V_{2}}$ and $R$, the rest are pressure variables, thermal variables, etc.

For one gas it's easy:

$$
\frac{PC_{V}^{*}}{RT}\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left ( \frac{P}{T} \right )T
\\
\frac{C_{V}^{*}}{RT}\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left ( \frac{P}{T} \right )\frac{T}{P}
\\
\frac{C_{V}^{*}}{R}\frac{d\ln(T)}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\left (\ln\left ( \frac{P}{T} \right ) \right )
$$

After integrating between the initial and final phase, we get:

$$\left ( \frac{T_{final}}{T_{initial}} \right )^{\frac{C_{V}^{*}}{R}} = \left ( \frac{P_{final}}{P_{initial}} \right )\left ( \frac{T_{initial}}{T_{final}} \right )$$

Comment: is pressure $P_1, P_2$ variable or constant?

Comment: Since there doesnt appear to be a coupling term  between $(T_1,P_1)$ and $(T_2,P_2)$ can you not have $F(T_1,P_1) = G(T_2,P_2) = \lambda$ where the functions are the set of ODES? you should have a closing equation since you have two set of unknowns and one equation.